# Azure Devops deployment pipeline: access output variable in different job

Tags: azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-server-2019

Using Azure Devops 2019 Server (On-Premises)

So I want my agentless job, User Intevention task named "Install" to run only when `IsServiceInstalled` variable is 0. I'm able to use this variable only within same job (agent), but not within other (agentless). [image]

No matter what I do, I get an exception stating something like:

```
Exception Message: Unrecognized value: 'dependencies'. Located at position 21 within expression: and(succeeded(), eq(<whatever i try to put here>, 0))
```

Code that sets variable:

```bsh
#Sets IsServiceInstalled to determine if service must be installed or updated

Get-Service "$(RabbitMQServiceName)" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if ($?) {
  echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=IsServiceInstalled;isOutput=true]1"
} else {
  echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=IsServiceInstalled;isOutput=true]0"
}
```

Task itself: [image]

1. I'm aware that I can use "depdendencies." to access that variable. [Use the output variable from a job in a condition in a subsequent job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#use-the-output-variable-from-a-job-in-a-condition-in-a-subsequent-job). But I don't get an option to name Job.
2. I'v ran my deployment with `system.debug=true` and found out `[SYSTEM_JOBNAME] --> [__default]` - so I tried setting  using `and(succeeded(), eq(dependencies.__default.Outputs['IsServiceInstalledTask.IsServiceInstalled'], 0))` - yeah, I get exception `Unrecognized value: 'dependencies'` - and no surprise as I never specified a dependency and I don't see where can I specify it within UI.
3. I don't have an option to set Job Name, so i'v tried setting various values I found within debug log (__default being the jobname I want my output variable from): `Stage_cb7edb91b40b4747845ae3564bf62723_2_9.Phase_1.__default...`, `Phase_1.__default...` or `__default...`

No matter what I try, I get the same Unrecognized value exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The great thing about writing a question is that I'v found the answer in official documentation: **NOT SUPPORTED** in classic pipeline.

Let me quote:

> ## Use output variables from tasks
>
> Some tasks define output variables, which you can consume in downstream steps, jobs, and stages. In YAML, you can access variables across jobs and stages by using dependencies..
>
> ### Use outputs in the same job
>
> In the Output variables section, give the producing task a reference name. Then, in a downstream step, you can use the form $(.) to refer to output variables.
>
> ### Use outputs in a different job
>
> You must use YAML to consume output

From [Use output variables from tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cbatch#use-output-variables-from-tasks) and click on Classic Tab